# Why ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid cannot be rescued in this Rails method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, activerecord, rescue

Why I cannot rescue anything in the following method?

```
def get_things
  begin
    things= @member.things.where("id>?",params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
    render( inline: "RESCUED ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid" )
    return
  rescue
    render( inline: "RESCUED something" )
    return
  end
  render( inline: "#{things.first.title}" )
end
```

When called with a valid id, it works:

```
$  curl -vd "id=3" http://localhost:3000/get_things
```

but if I pass a wrong one, such as:

```
$  curl -vd "id=3,0" http://localhost:3000/get_things
$  curl -vd "id='3'" http://localhost:3000/get_things
```

the exception isn't rescued:

```
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
<h1>
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
    in ApplicationController#get_things
</h1>
<pre>PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: &quot;'3'&quot;
```

Only when rendering happens inside begin/rescue block

```
def get_things
  begin
    things= @member.things.where("id>?",params[:id])
    render( inline: "#{things.first.title}" )
  rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
    render( inline: "RESCUED ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid" )
    return
  end
end
```

it works as expected:

```
$ curl -vd "id='3'" http://localhost:3000/get_things
  < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  RESCUED ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, the `things` in your case will be a class containg information on your query, but the query won't be executed till you try to acces an element based on the query (like `things.first`).

```
things= @member.things.where("id>?",params[:id]) # query not run
things= things.order("id desc") # still not run
things.first.title # now the query runs, the statement can be invalid
```

This is why it can't be rescued, because in your render line, where the exception occurs, not in the creation of the `things`.

This should be okay:

```
def get_things
  begin
    things= @member.things.where("id>?",params[:id])
    thing_title = things.first.title
  rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
    render( inline: "RESCUED ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid" )
    return
  rescue
    render( inline: "RESCUED something" )
    return
  end
  render( inline: "#{thing_title}" )
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that's quite interesting.

Answer (score -1):

You can change a parameter to int:

```
params[:id] = params[:id].to_i if params[:id].present?
things= @member.things.where("id>?",params[:id])
```

Or you can add validator for params in `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :things, :constraints => {:id => /\d+/}
```